# How to fix the Global.asax warnings in a Sitecore 9 (Update-1) Visual Studio solution?

Tags: visual-studio

In the [Sitecore® Experience Solution Developer Course](https://elearning.sitecore.net/Public/ContentDetails.aspx?id=9925D47D5E594EC7AC2E2FA2DB5B18DE) you learn to set up a Visual Studio solution for Sitecore 8 by doing the following steps:

1. Create a new **ASP.NET Web Application** using the **Empty ASP.NET 4.5.2 Template**.
2. Copy the **Global.asax**, **Web.config**, **Views\Web.config** files from the Sitecore Website folder into your Visual Studio project folder.
3. Add the assemblies **Sitecore.Kernel.dll**, **Sitecore.MVC.Analytics.dll**, and **Sitecore.MVC.dll** to your Visual Studio project.
4. Create a folder named **App_Config** in your Visual Studio project.

Optionally, you navigate to the **Global.asax** file and investigate the error list. If you notice that there are warnings, you can install the following NuGet packages with their depending packages.

- Microsoft.ASPNET.WebApi
- Microsoft.ASPNET.WebApi.Cors

These steps were not enough to fix the warnings in the **Global.asax** file. I had to install the following NuGet packages

- Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages

Recently, I followed these steps when setting up a Visual Studio solution for **Sitecore 9.0 (Initial Release)** and it worked fine.

Now, I am trying to do the same with **Sitecore 9.0 Update-1**, but I still get warnings from the Global.asax.

The first warning was:

> ASP.NET runtime error: The pre-application start initialization method Start on type WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Unable to open configSource file 'App_Config\Sitecore.config'

After adding the **App_Config\Sitecore.config** file to the Visual Studio project, it complained about more missing config files. After adding them, it started showing the following warning:

> ASP.NET runtime error: The pre-application start initialization method
>   Start on type WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode threw an
>   exception with the following error message: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I installed the **Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection** NuGet package. After that, it started giving me the following warning.

> ASP.NET runtime error: The pre-application start initialization method
>   Start on type WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode threw an
>   exception with the following error message: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

I tried to fix it by installing the **NETStandard.Library** NuGet package, but it didn't fix it. I ended up with a Visual Studio solution like that.

[image: How my Visual Studio solution looked like afterwards]

Have you guys managed to fix these warnings or do you advise me simply ignoring them?

Update: I am setting up a Visual Studio solution using **.NET Framework 4.7** and an **Empty ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)** template. I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: It is generally recommended not to mess with or edit the Global.asax file in Sitecore solutions (and instead use `Initialize` pipeline for anything you would normally do there). Do you get all the errors if you remove this file?

Comment: By removing Global.asax I don't get warnings anymore. I wonder why Sitecore would teach you to add this file in the first place. It is in the Sitecore® Experience Solution Developer Course I did 6 months ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @jammykam, I removed the `Global.asax`. It stopped the warnings being popped up in my Visual Studio. I don't know why the Sitecore online training teaches you to add this file to the Visual Studio project, but you shouldn't do it as it is NOT recommended adding custom code to Global.asax. If you need anything that you think should go no `Global.asax`, please use the `Initialize` pipeline or create a custom **Http Module**.